# how to write string in memory mapped file in VB6

Tags: vb6, ipc

I want to store a string in memory mapped file using VB6. I have to read that string in C#. My basic need is to implement IPC. Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this could be useful: [What is the easiest way to do inter process communication in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802475/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-inter-process-communication-in-c).

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you written anything yet? Are you stuck on some concept? Help us help you.

Comment: Where is your problem? Simple use it. (Google: vb6 winapi memory mapped file) - when I searched for it, the first found item offers a solution ...

Comment: @Alexander Obersht: I have to send a string with the long int value from VB6 to C#.

Comment: @theB: I am new to MMF. I got some nice piece of code in C# to read and write MMF. but i want to write in VB6 and read it in C#. I will really appreciate if you guide me with this.

Comment: I don't have much problem in C#, but in VB6 I am not getting any good help.